# add values into json object dynamically to extracting values from Array but not able to get correct output

Tags: javascript

Output is not according to me.
I want add value in text key from entityValue array  like this

```
[
    {
    text: 'apple',
  },
  {
    text: 'Banana',
  },
  {
    text: 'mango',
]
```

And text key name should be remain same.

```
[
    {
    text: 'mango',
    entityType: '@Fruits',
    alias: 'Fruits',
    userDefined: false
  },
  {
    text: 'mango',
    entityType: '@Fruits',
    alias: 'Fruits',
    userDefined: false
  },
  {
    text: 'mango',
    entityType: '@Fruits',
    alias: 'Fruits',
    userDefined: false
  }
]
```

```
let entityValue=[ 'apple', 'Banana', 'mango' ]
let part={};

if(entityValue.length>0){
            entityValue.forEach((index,value)=>{
              console.log(index);
              part ["text"] = index;  
              part ["entityType"] = '@' + entityTypeName;
              part ["alias"] = entityTypeName;
              part ["userDefined"] = false;
              partArr.push(part);
            });
            
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

simple use of [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) may solve your problem

```js
let entityValue = ['apple', 'Banana', 'mango']
let part = {};
let entityTypeName = 'Fruits';

let values = entityValue.map((val, index) => {

  return {
    text: val,
    entityType: '@' + entityTypeName,
    alias: entityTypeName,
    userDefined: false
  };
})

console.log(values);
```